# Python: Fusionar dos instancias de bucles anidados en una sola

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def limpiarCadena(cadena):

    cadenaLimpia = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-ZñÑçÇ]', '', str(cadena)) #Elimina todo caracter que no sea una letra (respeta eñes y cedillas)
    cadenaFinal = cadenaLimpia.lower().replace(' ', '')
    
    return cadenaFinal

def procesarCorreo(correoElectronico):

    nombreUsuario = correoElectronico.split('@')[0]
    nombreFinal = limpiarCadena(nombreUsuario)

    return nombreFinal

correoElectronico = 'avazquez@dominio.com'
nombreUsuario = procesarCorreo(correoElectronico)

nombres = {('ava', 30), ('', 0)}
apellidos = {('que', 44), ('', 0), ('qu', 102), ('vazquez', 149584), ('vaz', 2930), ('va', 109)}

mejoresCombinaciones = []
mayoresSimilitudes = []
similitudMinima = 0

for nombre in nombres:

    for apellido1 in apellidos:

        for apellido2 in apellidos:

            combinacion = limpiarCadena(nombre[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido1[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido2[0])
            similitud = SequenceMatcher(None, combinacion, nombreUsuario).ratio() #Valor entre 0 y 1
 
            if similitud > similitudMinima and similitud not in mayoresSimilitudes:

                mayoresSimilitudes.append(similitud)
                mayoresSimilitudes.sort()

                if len(mayoresSimilitudes) > 3: mayoresSimilitudes.pop(0)
                
print(mayoresSimilitudes)

for nombre in nombres:

    for apellido1 in apellidos:

        for apellido2 in apellidos:

            combinacion = limpiarCadena(nombre[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido1[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido2[0])
            similitud = SequenceMatcher(None, combinacion, nombreUsuario).ratio() #Valor entre 0 y 1
 
            if similitud in mayoresSimilitudes: mejoresCombinaciones.append([nombre, apellido1, apellido2, similitud])

for combinacion in mejoresCombinaciones: print(combinacion)
```

El código original funciona con entradas dinámicas (`correoElectronico`, `nombres` y `apellidos`),  esto sería un ejemplo concreto que produce las siguientes salidas:

```
print(mayoresSimilitudes)

[0.8888888888888888, 0.9333333333333333, 0.9411764705882353]

for combinacion in mejoresCombinaciones: print(combinacion)

[('ava', 30), ('', 0), ('vazquez', 149584), 0.8888888888888888]
[('ava', 30), ('vazquez', 149584), ('', 0), 0.8888888888888888]
[('', 0), ('', 0), ('vazquez', 149584), 0.9333333333333333]
[('', 0), ('vazquez', 149584), ('', 0), 0.9333333333333333]
[('', 0), ('vaz', 2930), ('vazquez', 149584), 0.8888888888888888]
[('', 0), ('va', 109), ('vazquez', 149584), 0.9411764705882353]
```

El objetivo es filtrar los tres mayores valores de `similitud` que encuentre de manera que sólo aquellos valores de `combinacion` apropiados se guarden en `mejoresCombinaciones`.

El código funciona pero como veis es muy feo; querría intentar resolverlo todo con una sola instancia del triple `for` anidado, si es posible.

Comment: Buen día, para entender bien lo que quieres, deseas combinar las dos instancias de 3 ciclos `for` anidados en una sola?

Comment: Quizás te sea útil [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Usado `for nombre, apellido1, apellido2 in product(nombres, apellidos, apellidos):`.

Comment: Sí, que sólo haya una instancia. Edito la pregunta para que quede más claro.

Comment: `itertools` permitiría fusionar los tres `for` en uno solo, pero lo que me interesa es no tener que repetir la segunda instancia de bucles `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo que tú me guardaría las similitudes dentro de un diccionario.
En ese mismo diccionario irán también las combinaciones asociadas.
Definimos `mayoresSimilitudes: 'dict[float, list[tuple]]' = {}`.
Para asegurarnos de que la primera iteración funciona añadamos un primer valor:
`mayoresSimilitudes[similitudMinima] = []`.

Escribiré el código usando [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) sólo para reducir niveles de indentación.

```py
for nombre, apellido1, apellido2 in product(nombres, apellidos, apellidos):

    combinacion = limpiarCadena(nombre[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido1[0]) + limpiarCadena(apellido2[0])
    similitud = SequenceMatcher(None, combinacion, nombreUsuario).ratio() #Valor entre 0 y 1

    # Si la similitud es demasiado pequeña, no me sirve esta combinación
    if similitud < similitudMinima:
        continue

    # Ordeno las similitudes ya calculadas
    similitudes_ordenadas = list(mayoresSimilitudes.keys())
    similitudes_ordenadas.sort()

    # Si la similitud es menor que la menor de ellas, no me sirve esta combinación
    if similitud < similitudes_ordenadas[0]:
        continue
    # Estoy seguro de que voy a añadir la combinación a mi diccionario
    # Obtengo la lista de combinaciones que tienen esta misma similitud
    combinaciones_empatadas = mayoresSimilitudes.setdefault(similitud, [])
    # Añado a esta lista la combinacion actual
    combinaciones_empatadas.append((nombre, apellido1, apellido2))

    # Si hay más llaves de las necesarias, elimino la más pequeña
    if len(similitudes_ordenadas) > 3:
        del mayoresSimilitudes[similitudes_ordenadas[0]]

# Imprimo las combinaciones que tienen las tres mayores similitudes
for similitud, combinaciones in mayoresSimilitudes.items():
    for combinacion in combinaciones:
        print(combinacion, similitud)
```

---

Hay margen para la optimización, ya que `similitudes_ordenadas` no tenemos por qué calcularla en todas las iteraciones del bucle:

```py
similitud = ...

if similitud < similitudMinima:
    continue
combinaciones_empatadas = mayoresSimilitudes.setdefault(similitud, [])
combinaciones_empatadas.append((nombre, apellido1, apellido2))

if len(mayoresSimilitudes) > 3:
    del mayoresSimilitudes[similitudMinima]
    similitudMinima = sorted(list(mayoresSimilitudes.keys()))[0]
```